# WebDriverManager unable to create Chrome Object in Docker container with SeleniumGrid and GitLab

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, gitlab-ci, selenium-grid, webdriver-manager

I am trying to run my tests in GitLab CICD pipeline with Docker Container and Selenium Grid configurations.
For Selenium driver initialization I am using WebDriverManger
I can see all images are pulled correctly in gitlab runner logs.
However as soon as WebDriverManager tries to connect to chromedriver I see below error

ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[1694602699.114][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)
Sep 13, 2023 10:58:19 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
[ERROR] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 309.248 s <<< FAILURE! - in As a user I want to test Login functionality
[ERROR] As a user I want to test Login functionality.Verify Home Page Functionality for Login Page  Time elapsed: 300.118 s  <<< ERROR!
io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.config.WebDriverManagerException: There was an error creating WebDriver object for Chrome
Caused by: io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.config.WebDriverManagerException: Timeout of 30 seconds creating WebDriver object
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:
Could not start a new session. New session request timed out
Host info: host: '48340880bd05', ip: '172.19.0.2'

My code to initialize chrome driver

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setHeadless(true);
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox","--disable-dev-shm-usage");
driver = WebDriverManager.chromedriver()
.capabilities(options)
.remoteAddress("http://selenium-hub:4444")
.create();
```

.gitlab-ci.yml file

```
stages:

- "test"

variables:
SELENIUM_SERVER_NAME: selenium-hub
SELENIUM_SERVER_URL: http://${SELENIUM_SERVER_NAME}:4444
DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375

services:

- docker:20.10.16-dind

test:
stage: test
image: docker/compose
before_script:
\- docker-compose up -d selenium-hub chrome chrome2
\- sleep 10
\- echo "before script"
\- echo ${SELENIUM_SERVER_URL}
\- echo docker ps -a
\- docker-compose run ping curl ${SELENIUM_SERVER_URL}/status
script:
\- docker-compose run tests mvn clean test

artifacts:
when: always
name: "report"
paths:
\- target/surefire-reports/\*\*
expire_in: 7 days
```

docker-compose file

```
version: "3"
services:
chrome:
image: selenium/node-chrome:latest
shm_size: 2gb
depends_on:
\- selenium-hub
environment:
\- SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=${SELENIUM_SERVER_NAME}
\- SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
\- SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
\- JAVA_OPTS=-Dwebdriver.chrome.whitelistedIps=

chrome2:
image: selenium/node-chrome:latest
shm_size: 2gb
depends_on:
\- selenium-hub
environment:
\- SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=${SELENIUM_SERVER_NAME}
\- SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
\- SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
\- JAVA_OPTS=-Dwebdriver.chrome.whitelistedIps=

selenium-hub:
image: selenium/hub:latest
container_name: ${SELENIUM_SERVER_NAME}
ports:
\- "4442:4442"
\- "4443:4443"
\- "4444:4444"

ping:
image: alpine/curl

tests:
\# image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-11
image: markhobson/maven-chrome:jdk-11
working_dir: /app
volumes:
\- ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}:/app
environment:
ENVIRONMENT: remote
SELENIUM_SERVER_URL: ${SELENIUM_SERVER_URL}
```